# Time stamping of Transactions

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, development, bitcoin-core-development, altcoin-development

In Bitcoin Blockchain, every block has a time stamp. My question is, Is there any time stamp on an individual transaction, once it is propagated on the network, and once it was included in the Block?

Answer (score 1):

no, a transaction has no time stamp. Details can be found here: https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#transactions